# Consecutive application of Modulo Operator

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Is it true that $a \bmod n\equiv (a \bmod n)\bmod  n$?

Is is possible to show intuitively why ?

Comment: The answer is yes.  One explanation is simply that for any $x$ between $0$ and $n-1$, $x \bmod n = x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a\bmod n$ is by definition the congruence class of the remainder in the division of $a$ by $n$ .

$(a \bmod n)\bmod  n$ is the congruence class of the remainder in the division of this remainder  by $n$. But, as this remainder is less than $n$, the latter remainder is the first remainder itself.

Comment: How in the world do you have a reputation of 1. Is SE joking right now?